# Extracting quoted part from string

Tags: string, go, double-quotes

I am trying following code to extract quoted part from a string:

```
package main
import ("fmt")
func main(){
    var oristr = "This is a \"test string\" for testing only"
    var quotedstr = ""
    var newstr = ""
    var instring = false
    fmt.Println(oristr)
    for i,c := range oristr {
        fmt.Printf("Char number: %d; char: %c\n", i, c);
        if c = `"` {
            if instring
            {instring=false}
            else {instring=true}}
        if instring
        {quotedstr += c}
        else {newstr += c}
    }
    fmt.Printf("Newstr: %s; quotedstr = %s", newstr, quotedstr )
}
```

However, I am getting following error:

```
# command-line-arguments
./getstring.go:11:14: syntax error: c = `"` used as value
./getstring.go:12:15: syntax error: unexpected newline, expecting { after if clause
./getstring.go:14:4: syntax error: unexpected else, expecting }
./getstring.go:15:3: syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

Why I am getting this error and how can this be corrected?

Also, is this approach all right or some other approach may be better?

Comment: Firstly, `if c = \`"\` {` should be `if c == \`"\` {` (You are using a single equals sign where you mean to use a double one).

Comment: What @Collierre said, and also it's `'"'`, not `\`"\``. `c` is not a string but a rune, so use single quotes to construct a rune.

Comment: ... another thing, Go does not allow to use `{` on a new line. So reformat your code, it's not only unreadable but also invalid syntactically.

Comment: OK, it works with `c == '"'` and correction of `{`. Why are characters called `rune` in golang?

Comment: @rnso, is there some reason you can't use regex for this?

Comment: I am not well versed with regex. I did ask for better approaches. I will appreciate an answer using regex.

Comment: Go uses UTF-8 for source code. A rune allows go to represent any character in the UTF-8 number-space.

Comment: @rnso I don't know why they chose that name, but you could speculate that they decided not to use `char` since that type in some other languages is known to hold exactly one byte of data and not more, while a `rune` may hold more than just one byte and so to avoid confusion they chose the latter. But that's just the first thing that came to my mind, if you really want to know you may go to the go-nuts mailing list and try to solicit the answer from the Go team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most basic way of getting what you want. It could be improved to be more robust etc.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var oristr = "This is a \"test string\" for containing multiple \"test strings\" and another \"one\" here"
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`"[^"]+"`)
    newStrs := re.FindAllString(oristr, -1)
    for _, s := range newStrs {
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great. What if there are more than one quoted strings in `oristr`?

Comment: I've modified it now to support that.

Comment: With `"[^"]*"` (`*` instead of `+`), even `""` will be picked up correctly.